# Let $a_1 > 1$, and for $n \in N$, define $a_{n+1} = 2 - 1/a_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $a_1 > 1$, and for $n \in N$, define $a_{n+1} = 2 - {1\over a_n}$.
Show that the sequence $a_n$ is monotone and bounded. Find $lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$

So far I have it set up like this (not sure if it's the right way)

monotonic: $a_n < a_{n + 1}$ (increasing) or $a_n > a_{n+1}$ (decreasing)

base case: $n = 1$
we know that $a_1 > 1$ and $a_{n+1} = 2 - {1\over a_n}$
$a_{1+1} = 2 - {1\over a_1}$

I have no idea how to show that it's decreasing as n goes up with the base case being 1. Would I have to show the next one ($a_3$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with an experiment. Say let $a_1=2$ and see what is happening.

It appears as if the terms are getting smaller and this is your proposition.

> The sequence is monotone decreasing

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=1-\frac{2}{a_n}-a_n=\frac{2a_n-1-a_n^2}{a_n}=\frac{-a_n^2+2a_n-1}{a_n}.$$

Can you say anything about the quadratic $-x^2+2x-1$? The proof of this proposition is in there.

Further experimentation *suggests* that the limit is one and indeed note that if $a_n\approx1$ then
$$a_{n+1}= 2-\frac{1}{a_n}\approx 2-1=1,$$
so $a_{n+1}\approx a_n$. Perhaps $a_n>1$? In fact this follows inductively... if $a_n>1$ then so is $a_{n+1}$. Can you show this?

Now we think that $a_n\rightarrow 1$. We know the limit exists because the sequence is bounded and monotone. What could you say if the limit were $1+\varepsilon$?

Comment: From the quadratic I got $-(a_n-1)^2$. Whoops, I'm still typing more and I just figured out I can't press enter here without it posting.

Comment: So for the base case I have $n = 1$, $a_1 > 1$ and $a_2 = 2 - {1 \over a_n}$ then $a_1 > 2 - {1 \over 1} = 1$ which is true. Now assume $a_n$ is true, I want to show that $a_{n+1}$ is also true for $n \in N$. $a_n > a_{n+1}$ Now I take the reciprocal of both sides, multiply by negative 1 and add 2 to get $2 - {1\over a_n} > 2 - {1\over a_{n+1}}$ resulting in $a_{n+1} > a_{n+2}$? I hope I'm doing this somewhat okay so far. How would I show that it's bounded? Is showing that it's bounded the same as finding the limit of $a_n$?

Comment: Now what do you know about $-(a_n-1)^2$? To show the sequence is decreasing you only need to look at that quadratic.

To show that it is bounded (below) you show that all of the elements of the sequence are bigger than something (e.g 1).

Then you use the fact that a monotone bounded sequence is convergent to justify that the limit exists.

Now you maybe solve $a_{n+1}=a_n$ to find a candidate limit (e.g. 1) and you try and prove that $a_n\rightarrow 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a_{n+1}=u(a_n)$ where $u:x\mapsto2-1/x$ is increasing on $x\gt0$ hence, either $a_2\gt a_1$ and then $(a_n)$ is increasing, or $a_2\lt a_1$ and then $(a_n)$ is decreasing.

Now, $a_1\gt1$ and $a_2=u(a_1)$ hence one must show that $u(x)\lt x$ for every $x\gt1$. This should be doable, no?